# Selenium and HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have been using selenium to try and scrape some info from a database of company data. The database is private and it requires a password so, unfortunately, I cannot share the whole python code, nor the whole HTML code.

Here's the part of the HTML code required for my problem

```html
<li>
   <a id="reportsForm:j_idt320:3:j_idt325" href="#" class="ui-commandlink ui-widget nav-item " onclick="PrimeFaces.addSubmitParam('reportsForm',{'reportsForm:j_idt320:3:j_idt325':'reportsForm:j_idt320:3:j_idt325'}).submit('reportsForm','_blank');return false;" target="_blank">
    <span id="reportsForm:j_idt320:3:l2" data-hasqtip="reportsForm:j_idt320:3:tooltipID">Avaliação de Risco Plus</span></a>
</li>
```

In this part of the code, I need to click on a linked text, and I have tried countless ways (including implicit waits, finding elements by class name, id, xpath and so on...) and I have realised that the only way to locate the element is through the following command:

```
afg = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Avaliação de Risco Plus')
```

However, when I try to click on it, I run into the following error message:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="#" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'trackOutboundLink(\'Relatório Sugerido Alerta\', \'Click\', \'...\', \'\', \'_blank\');','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'companyForm\'),{\'companyForm:tableLastUpdate:1:j_idt262\':\'companyForm:tableLastUpdate:1:j_idt262\'},\'_blank\')');return false">Avaliação de Risco Plus</a> is not clickable at point (550, 745). Other element would receive the click: <div id="fundo">...</div>
```

I understand python is not letting me click on this what I defined as afg, because it is intercepted by the link on href = "#". But that is exactly the link I want to click!

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is that element in viewPoint ? or Do you have to scroll to see that element?

Comment: Innitialy yes. But I maximized the window in order to see it already, and I enconter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still in view point, you can try with below code :

```
element_to_be_clickable = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Avaliação de Risco Plus')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_be_clickable).click().perform()
```

or

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_link_text('Avaliação de Risco Plus')).click().perform()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! It says I'm using an invalid selector.... Is there something else I can try?

Comment: OMG I hadn't seen the second option! IT WORKED!!!!! Thank you sooooo much!!!!!